# Is it safe to use lubricant or antiseize on DI injectors?

Tags: fuel-injectors, gasoline-direct-injection, anti-seize

I'm working on a 2010 Range Rover with the 5.0 which has direct injection, but my question is about direct injection engines in general; not necessarily just this model.

I'm going to be putting new injectors in soon, and noticed the instructions say not to use any lubricant of any kind, and from what I've seen that's the recommendation for all DI engines. These injectors, like all direct injection injectors it seems, are tough to extract after they've been in use for a while, to say the least.

My question is why are you not supposed to use a lubricant or anti seize of some sort? There's anti seize products out there for diesel injectors and glow plugs, like Febi 26712 or regular nickel anti seize that seem like they would work wonderfully. The only difference I can see between diesel injectors and/or glow plugs and DI injectors is the latter uses a teflon seal near the end.

I haven't been able to find much information on the topic, so thanks in advance!

Comment: I've not done any work with DI injectors, but if the instructions say "don't use it" ... I'd suggest that's probably a good way to go.

Comment: It's true! The logic escapes me though and that's what's irking me. I like to understand the reasoning for things so I can make an informed decision.

Comment: anti-seize is not a lubricant